# Excel VBA String Conversion with Math Properties

Tags: arrays, excel, string, vba, special-characters

I have a curiosity that has piqued my interest and has stumped me. I have a situation where I have a bunch of strings, some with Math symbols, and some that are just Characters. Some of these strings are very long, some are not, however, I would like to add a Chr(10) after the complete string of any string that has a Math symbol (specifically +, -) and then continue reading the string for the next Math symbol, and inserting a Chr(10) before it as well.

The end result should look something like this:

```
10+20+30+40 50+60+70+80 123a 123 123b 345 123c 123 123d 123 90+100+110+120 123 123 231 123

Converts to: 

10+20+30+40  
50+60+70+80 
123a 123 123b 345 123c 123 123d 123 
90+100+110+120 
123 123 231 123
```

Where the equations have no spaces, the plain letters (could be a mix of numbers and letters) could have spaces, but gets separated when a Math symbol is found.

I was looking online for some clues and I think I am very close to figuring it out. It seems a split, merge, or Right(), Left(), then Len() function is the answer.

```
 If Len(SearchString) = "+" Or Len(SearchString) = "-" Then
    SearchString = Left(SearchString, Chr(10))
 End If
```

This however doesn't work. I may not understand the Len, Left, and Right functions well enough but I am pretty positive that SearchString is the right course of action. It is also worth noting that the If/End If statement that I provided does function, it doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: Thank you all this answers my question! I ended up using the Option Explicit answer from Juan Medel, as it was the simplest for me to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of using regular expressions.  I use the `.Replace` method

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitter()
    Dim S As String, RE As Object
    Const spat As String = "((?:(?:\w+[+-])+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)|(?:^|\s)((?:\w+\s+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)"
    Dim sRes As Variant

S = "10+20+30+40 50+60+70+80 123a 123 123b 345 123c 123 123d 123 90+100+110+120 123 123 231 123"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = spat
    sRes = .Replace(S, vbLf & "$1$2")
    MsgBox sRes
End With

End Sub
```

How to apply this will depend on your data setup; going through your original data and spitting out the results someplace.

### Splitter

```
((?:(?:\w+[+-])+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)|(?:^|\s)((?:\w+\s+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `((?:(?:\w+[+-])+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)`

  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `((?:(?:\w+[+-])+)+\w+)`

    - [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:(?:\w+[+-])+)+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
      - [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\w+[+-])+`

        - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
        - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

          - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
        - [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[+-]`

          - [The literal character “+”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `+`
          - [The literal character “-”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
    - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\s|$)`

    - [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\s`

      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
    - [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `$`

      - [Assert position at the very end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:^|\s)((?:\w+\s+)+\w+)(?=\s|$)`

  - [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:^|\s)`

    - [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `^`

      - [Assert position at the beginning of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
    - [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\s`

      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `((?:\w+\s+)+\w+)`

    - [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\w+\s+)+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
      - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

        - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

        - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
    - [Match a single character that is a “word character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\s|$)`

    - [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\s`

      - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
    - [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `$`

      - [Assert position at the very end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`

$1$2

- [Insert a line feed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `␊`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In a rough way it does what you need.

```
sentence() = Split(10+20+30+40 50+60+70+80 123a 123 123b 345 123c 123 123d 123 90+100+110+120 123 123 231 123)

 For i = 0 To UBound(sentence)
  acu_str = sentence(i)
   If InStr(sentence(i), "+") = 0 And InStr(sentence(i), "-") = 0 Then
    Do While InStr(sentence(i + 1), "+") = 0 And InStr(sentence(i + 1), "-") = 0
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
     acu_str = acu_str + " " + sentence(i + 1)
    i = i + 1
    Loop
   ErrorHandling:
  End If
 Debug.Print acu_str & vbCr
 Next i
```

Comment: I have multiple ranges that this needs to work on so can I simply replace "Sentence() =" with range?

Comment: Sure, place it within the Split function.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not ideal but uses a regex to do the breaking.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim tests(), i As Long
    tests = Array("10+20+30+40 50+60+70+80 123a 123 123b 345 123c 123 123d 123 90+100+110+120 123 123 231 123")
    For i = LBound(tests) To UBound(tests)
        Debug.Print ReplaceString(tests(i))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ReplaceString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
Dim matches As Object, match As Object
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = "(\w+\+|\-)+(\w)+"
            If .TEST(inputString) Then
              Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
              For Each match In matches
                  inputString = Replace$(Replace$(inputString, Chr$(32) & match, Chr$(10) & match), match & Chr$(32), match & Chr$(10))
              Next
              ReplaceString = Trim$(inputString)
            Else
              ReplaceString = inputString
            End If
  End With
End Function
```

---

1st Capturing Group `(\w+\+|\-)+`

`\+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

1st Alternative `\w+\+`

`\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

`\+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\+` matches the character `+` literally (case sensitive)

2nd Alternative `\-`
`\-` matches the character - literally (case sensitive)

2nd Capturing Group `(\w)+`

`\+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_`])

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kjvv06/2)

Thanks to @RonRosenfeld for helping me to improve my regex.

Comment: Your regex assumes there will never be a non-digit in the string with the arithmetical operators.  Might or might not be a problem.  But if a substring is like `50+60+70a+80b`...

Comment: I would just replace `[0-9]` with `\w`

Comment: Doh! Nice! Thank you

Comment: How do I get the Option Explicit to work in my macro? I have a different Sub routine that I'm also running in conjunction with this?

Comment: You just put it at the top of each module before anything else. Or switch it on as an [option](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)  .Visual Basic Editor>Tools>Options>Check Require Variable Declaration. I would advise enabling the option. It forces you to write better code.

Comment: Did this question get answered by the way?

Answer (score 1):

InStr and InStrRev should be able to handle the splits.

```
Option Explicit    

Function splitString(str As String)

    Dim a As Long, b As Long

    a = InStr(1, str, Chr(32))
    b = InStr(1, str, Chr(43))

    Do While a > 0 And b > 0

        If b > a Then
            a = InStrRev(str, Chr(32), b)
        End If

        Mid(str, a, 1) = Chr(10)

        b = InStr(a, str, Chr(43))
        a = InStr(a, str, Chr(32))

    Loop

    splitString = str

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was hoping for thank you! It is a roundabout way and I didnt understand the Option Explicit function, however this did 100000000% what I was aiming for thank you so very much! I realized belatedly that I had to type it into the cell haha

Comment: It is absolutely what I needed but I was wondering how to add a 3rd variable such as a "-" sign to the loop? I tried using the or function and it got mixed results, half of the lines would "split" but the others would give a value error?

Comment: If you're changing the conditions of your question such that the new conditions render a current answer invalid, then you should finish with this question 'as-is' and post a new question with the new conditions, new sample data and new expected results, [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif)